# How to design ItemsTable with Bisd table correctly in Auction website

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm making a auction website, my question is how do I design the bid winner correct way? For example: 
Items Table:

```
-id
-user_id(fk user)
-title
```

Bids Table:

```
-id
-item_id(fk Items)
-user_id(fk user)
-price
```

If I want to make the winner bid, I should add `winner_bid_id` column into `Items` table and References to bids table. Like this:

Items Table:

```
    -id
    -user_id(fk user)
    -title
    -winner_bid_id(fk Bids)
```

Or should I add one column like `is_winner` into Bids Table, like this:
Bids Table:

```
-id
-item_id(fk Items)
-user_id(fk user)
-price
-is_winner
```

Which one is better? I have references this: [database structure for bidding site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15323646/database-structure-for-bidding-site). But If with option 1(add `winner_bid_id` into `Items` table and reference `Bids` table) I will have two table references each other, and when I want to remove a row in Items table, I have the foreign key error, What should I do?

Comment: Getting a foreign-key-error is an indication that FKs is not the right thing.  Perhaps you only need an `INDEX`.

Answer (score 1):

There can be only one winning bid -- presumably.

The better way to add such a relationship is with a single column in the `items` table, assuming that each "item" is really a separate auction.

However, you want to be sure that the bid is for the item.  So, introduce a (redundant) index on `bids(item_id, user_id)` and have the foreign key relationship be to this index.  That will ensure that the winning bid is for the correct item.

If you add a column `is_winner` into the `bids` table, you will need to use triggers to ensure that there is at most one winning bid.  Some databases allow filtered unique indexes which would get around this.  MySQL does not, as far as I know.

Comment: But if I do with option 1, I will get **The Circular Reference**, I have try this, when I want to remove an items, I have an foreign key error, and this option is ensure the integrity?

Comment: `BEGIN; DELETE; DELETE; COMMIT;`  Or use `ON DELETE CASCADE`.